# Flutter error: 'Vertical viewport was given unbounded height' and 'nthrow' isn't a type

Tags: flutter, dart, debugging

I am working on a flutter project using VS Code and when I changed the device I was using to preview my work I started getting an error. This is what my debug console is showing me:

```
Flutter assets will be downloaded from https://storage.flutter-io.cn. Make sure you trust this source!
Launching lib\main.dart on SM A037F in debug mode...
main.dart:1
Flutter assets will be downloaded from https://storage.flutter-io.cn. Make sure you trust this source!
/E:/AppData/new/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/debug.dart:328:13: Error: 'nthrow' isn't a type.
            nthrow FlutterError.fromParts(<DiagnosticsNode>[
            ^^^^^^
/E:/AppData/new/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/debug.dart:328:20: Error: Expected ';' after this.
            nthrow FlutterError.fromParts(<DiagnosticsNode>[
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^
/E:/AppData/new/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/debug.dart:328:32: Error: Expected an identifier, but got '.'.

Try inserting an identifier before '.'.
            nthrow FlutterError.fromParts(<DiagnosticsNode>[
                               ^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception
2

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'E:\AppData\new\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1201

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'E:\AppData\new\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 14s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

This is the debug.dart part that is being referenced on the error from line 327

```
if (!constraints.hasBoundedHeight) {
            nthrow FlutterError.fromParts(<DiagnosticsNode>[
              ErrorSummary('Vertical viewport was given unbounded height.'),
              ErrorDescription(
                'Viewports expand in the scrolling direction to fill their container. '
                'In this case, a vertical viewport was given an unlimited amount of '
                'vertical space in which to expand. This situation typically happens '
                'when a scrollable widget is nested inside another scrollable widget.',
              ),
              ErrorHint(
                'If this widget is always nested in a scrollable widget there '
                'is no need to use a viewport because there will always be enough '
                'vertical space for the children. In this case, consider using a '
                'Column or Wrap instead. Otherwise, consider using a '
                'CustomScrollView to concatenate arbitrary slivers into a '
                'single scrollable.',
              ),
            ]);
          }
```

Help me fix this issue so that I can resume working on my project. I am using

```
Flutter 3.10.2 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git 
Framework • revision 9cd3d0d9ff (12 days ago) • 2023-05-23 20:57:28 -0700
Engine • revision 90fa3ae28f
Tools • Dart 3.0.2 • DevTools 2.23.1
```

I have tried running `flutter clean`, `flutter pub get`, `flutter pub cache repair` but none of them seem to fix my issue. When I run `flutter doctor` this is the output I get:

```
Flutter assets will be downloaded from https://storage.flutter-io.cn. Make sure you trust this source!
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.2, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.2965], locale en-KE)
[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.1.0-rc1)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.6.2)
[√] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
[√] VS Code (version 1.78.2)
[√] Connected device (4 available)
[√] Network resources

• No issues found!
```

Comment: Hey there, might sound a bit off but have you tried killing VSCode and re-opening your project ? I've been in situations where changing something of that kind would break the code for no reason which I solved this way.

Comment: Yes, I have even tried opening the project with android studio and it's showing the same error.

Comment: Oh wait a minute, in your debug.dart file line 328, nthrow ain't a typo ? isn't it supposed to be throw instead ?

Comment: Thanks, it's now working after I removed the n, I had not noticed the typo.